# Retrieve value from nested json object

Tags: javascript, json, filter, lodash

I have the following json object:

```
{
  "name": "Cairo",
  "title": "Lots to do in cairo",
  "categories": ["travel", "holiday"],
  "image": [
    {
      "thumbnail": {
        "src": "/images/thumbnail/cairo.jpg",
        "height": 27,
        "width": 60
      }
    },
    {
      "mobile": {
        "src": "/images/mobile/cairo.jpg",
        "height": 106,
        "width": 236
      }
    },
    {
      "original": {
        "src": "/images/original/cairo.jpg",
        "height": 866,
        "width": 1920
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to access the 'src' value of the 'original' image for this particular object using jquery/lodash/javascript.

I can output the value using the folllowing:

```
var originalSrc = _.result(obj, 'image[2].original.src');
```

The problem with this is that I have to hardcode the [2], but the ordering of the image variants in this json response aren't fixed, so the next time it could return the 'mobile' src instead.

Does anyone have any solutions/ideas around this?

Thanks

Ashil

Comment: Are you able to change the input json array?

Comment: If image was an object, you can access it like a property with `image.original`, otherwise you need to create a special function to loop through the array and find an object with property "original"

Answer (score 0):

The JSON is poorly laid out (as comments above point out), but if you can't change it, this one-liner should work:

`obj.image.filter(function (x) { return Object.keys(x)[0] == 'original' })[0].original.src`

Answer (score 0):

Can try this:

```js
var json = {
  "name": "Cairo",
  "title": "Lots to do in cairo",
  "categories": ["travel", "holiday"],
  "image": [
    {
      "thumbnail": {
        "src": "/images/thumbnail/cairo.jpg",
        "height": 27,
        "width": 60
      }
    },
    {
      "mobile": {
        "src": "/images/mobile/cairo.jpg",
        "height": 106,
        "width": 236
      }
    },
    {
      "original": {
        "src": "/images/original/cairo.jpg",
        "height": 866,
        "width": 1920
      }
    }
  ]
}

var desiredObject = json.image.filter(function(image){return Object.keys(image)[0] == 'original'; })[0]

console.log(desiredObject);
console.log(desiredObject.original.src);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to achieve the solution in multiple Steps.

1. Get the Object Properties, in your case, `thumbnail, mobile, original` are the properties of the objects inside the array inside the image object.
   `Object.keys(objJSON.image)` retrieves all the properties inside the array, in this case since it an array the result would be `[0,1,2]`
2. Find the "original" Image object inside the Image object. The Properties in an object can be accessed using `object["PropertyName"]` syntax and [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method returns the first element matching the criteria. So, basically, we try to find the object which contains the property with name "original".

   `Object.keys(objJSON.image).find(i => objJSON.image[i]["original"]);`
3. Retrieve the `src` property from the object.
   `objJSON.image[originalImageIndexInArray].original.src;`

   ```js
   var objJSON = {
     "name": "Cairo",
     "title": "Lots to do in cairo",
     "categories": ["travel", "holiday"],
     "image": [
       {
         "thumbnail": {
           "src": "/images/thumbnail/cairo.jpg",
           "height": 27,
           "width": 60
         }
       },
       {
         "mobile": {
           "src": "/images/mobile/cairo.jpg",
           "height": 106,
           "width": 236
         }
       },
       {
         "original": {
           "src": "/images/original/cairo.jpg",
           "height": 866,
           "width": 1920
         }
       }
     ]
   };

   var originalImageIndexInArray = Object.keys(objJSON.image).find(i => objJSON.image[i]["original"]);

   var originalImageSrc = objJSON.image[originalImageIndexInArray].original.src;

   console.log(originalImageSrc);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [find](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#find) to obtain an item with an `original` key from the `image` array, use [get](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#find) to get the `src`. Note that we need to use [chain](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#chain) to chain methods from an array conversion, `data.image`, into an object through `find`.

```
var result = _.chain(data.image)
  .find('original')
  .get('original.src')
  .value();
```

```js
var data = {
  "name": "Cairo",
  "title": "Lots to do in cairo",
  "categories": ["travel", "holiday"],
  "image": [
    {
      "thumbnail": {
        "src": "/images/thumbnail/cairo.jpg",
        "height": 27,
        "width": 60
      }
    },
    {
      "mobile": {
        "src": "/images/mobile/cairo.jpg",
        "height": 106,
        "width": 236
      }
    },
    {
      "original": {
        "src": "/images/original/cairo.jpg",
        "height": 866,
        "width": 1920
      }
    }
  ]
};

var result = _.chain(data.image)
  .find('original')
  .get('original.src')
  .value();
  
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

An alternative solution is to use [map](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#map) to get the image source, and then use [first](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#first) to get the value.

```
var result = _(data.image).map('original.src').first();
```

```js
var data = {
  "name": "Cairo",
  "title": "Lots to do in cairo",
  "categories": ["travel", "holiday"],
  "image": [
    {
      "thumbnail": {
        "src": "/images/thumbnail/cairo.jpg",
        "height": 27,
        "width": 60
      }
    },
    {
      "mobile": {
        "src": "/images/mobile/cairo.jpg",
        "height": 106,
        "width": 236
      }
    },
    {
      "original": {
        "src": "/images/original/cairo.jpg",
        "height": 866,
        "width": 1920
      }
    }
  ]
};

var result = _(data.image).map('original.src').first();
  
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```